# Create a dropzone programmatically with variable numeric div id as container

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm trying to create a dropzone programmatically, in the sense that the clickable element of the dropzone won't exist until a certain other action has been activated.

```
$("#anotherdiv").click(function(){
  var id = $(this).parent().attr("id"); // a number greater than 1...
  $(this).parent().html("<img id=\"replaceme"+id+"\" src=\"/replace.me.png\" class=\"replaceme\" />");
        new Dropzone("div#"+id, {
        url: "/upload.image.php",
        clickable: "#replaceme"+id
      });

});
```

This works when I set the dropzone to be `document.body` instead of the particular element, but not as above, where I have a specific numeric id for the dropzone. How do I get the latter to work?

Comment: Can you share some html?

Comment: it seems that it's because i am trying to include multiple dropzones on the same page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19945125/multiple-dropzone-js-single-page